# Laravel textarea has white space and not showing value from db?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple textarea tag like this:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('main') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label id="main2" for="main" class="col-md-4 control-label">Main</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea id="main" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Main Text"
            title="More main text"  name="main" value="{{ $entity->main }}">
            </textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('main'))
            <span class="help-block">
               <strong>{{ $errors->first('main') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

However, instead of actual output from db I get white space so if I click on the field it feels like I have pressed tab 3 times. How can that be solved?

Comment: As per @RAUSHAN KUMAR's answer, textarea has no value attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Textarea doesn't support the `value` attribute. To display the value in textarea you have to place the variable inside the opening and closing `<textarea>value</textarea>` tags. So use like this.

```
<textarea id="main" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Main Text" title="More main text"  name="main">{{ $entity->main }}</textarea>
```